# How do I separate the input and targets from Pytorch Fashion MNIST?

Tags: python, pytorch

The Fashion MNIST dataset is implemented pretty weirdly in Pytorch. I want to do something like:

```
X, y = FashionMNIST
```

But in reality, it's a little more complicated. This is what I have:

```
from torchvision.datasets import FashionMNIST
train = FashionMNIST(root='.', download=True, train=True)
print(train)
```

The output:

```
Dataset FashionMNIST
    Number of datapoints: 60000
    Root location: c:/users/nicolas/documents/data/fashionmnist
    Split: Train
```

What *one* observation looks like:

```
print(train[0])
```

```
(<PIL.Image.Image image mode=L size=28x28 at 0x20868074780>, 9)
```

I could only do it for *one* observation.

```
X, y = train[0]
```

So how do I separate the input and targets?

Comment: what is the shape of `train`, the last index must be labels

Comment: `AttributeError: 'FashionMNIST' object has no attribute 'shape'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`FashionMNIST` object has `data` and `targets` attributes.

You can simply write

```
X, y = train.data, train.targets
```

and then you can see the shapes

```
X.shape, y.shape
```

> (torch.Size([60000, 28, 28]), torch.Size([60000]))